# How to use TableExport (html table to Excel) in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using TableExport by https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport/ by I have not been able to figure out how to use it in an Angular4 environment.

Comment: Take a look at the [TableExport + Angular 4](https://github.com/clarketm/tableexport_angular4_webpack2_app) starter which outlines a basic usage.

Comment: Your particular [issue](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport/issues/65) should now be fixed as of the latest stable release ([v4.0.8](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport/releases/tag/v4.0.8)).